# Masking an object to make it appear as if it goes behind the item it's rotating around

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make a 'dot' orbit around another object (circle) but due to the `z-index` the dot always appears above the circle it is meant orbiting around.

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/ROVZXd?editors=1100

Ideally the 2nd half of the animation would take place behind the object so it's not seen until it comes out the other side - is that possible?

I thought about fading out the object that is moving around but I don't think that would give a smooth/masked effect?

A bit stuck as to how I'd mask this area as I can't see a way the CSS would know it's meant to be hidden. I thought maybe I could change the `z-index` 50% though the animation it and reset it at 0%/100% but that doesn't appear to do anything.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```css
.earth {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.orbit {
  border: 2px #eee transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotateZ(60deg) rotateY(60deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 140px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.orbit .moon {
  animation: move ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(-70deg); z-index: 20;
  }
  50% {
    z-index: -20;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(-270deg) rotateY(-70deg); z-index: 20;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <div class="orbit">
    <div class="moon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.independent-software.com/deconstructing-css-3-making-of-css3-solar-system-animation-3d-transformations.html

Comment: The problem is present in the stack snippet but not in the codepen link - is the codepen yours or something you're trying to replicate?

Comment: I've actually continued playing around with it and added a `z-index` to its parent at 100% which has sorted it I think. Thought I'm not sure why applying the negative `z-index` at 50% didn't work and 100% did as it kinda does just need to be set halfway through!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have solved this by adding a negative `z-index` to an animation applied to the parent `.orbit`

Link: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/wZdpRw?editors=1100

I initially applied this at 50% through the animation as that should be the furthest away the dot is before it comes back behind the larger circle. However this didn't work, setting it on 100% did work. Not entirely sure why but it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

The initial issue was due to the fact that you are applying `z-index` to the parent element and doing so it will impossible to make the child to move behind it ([Why elements with any z-index value can never cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)) thus changin `z-index` is useless

Even if you remove the `z-index` from the parent you still have the transform that is also creating a stacking context making impossible to the child element to move behind so you cannot make the `.moon` to move behind the `.earth`.

The only way to do it (like you already noticed) is to remove `z-index` from the `.earth` to avoid the earth creating a stacking context and animate z-index of orbit to make the orbit AND the moon moving behind the earth (not only the moon).

Add some coloration to better see this:

```css
.earth {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.orbit {
  animation: hide ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background:red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotateZ(60deg) rotateY(60deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 140px;
}

.orbit .moon {
  animation: move ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(-70deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(-270deg) rotateY(-70deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    z-index: 20;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: -20;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <div class="orbit">
    <div class="moon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if you add back `z-index` to earth it will stop working because of the stacking context:

```css
.earth {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  z-index:2;
}

.orbit {
  animation: hide ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background:red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotateZ(60deg) rotateY(60deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 140px;
}

.orbit .moon {
  animation: move ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(-70deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(-270deg) rotateY(-70deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    z-index: 20;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: -20;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <div class="orbit">
    <div class="moon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try key-framing the opacity:

```css
.earth {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.orbit {
  border: 2px #eee transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 140px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotateZ(60deg) rotateY(60deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 140px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.orbit .moon {
  animation: move ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(-70deg); opacity: 1;
  }
  56% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  58% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  78% {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg) translateX(70px) rotateZ(-270deg) rotateY(-70deg); opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <div class="orbit">
    <div class="moon"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, but there's a rather sharp pop-in and pop-out on either end. Key-framing the opacity won't allow the circle to disappear right to left, and re-appear right to left as it needs to.

Comment: I think I've managed to solve this by adding a negative `z-index` in a separate animation: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/wZdpRw?editors=1100 - seems to work! But not sure why applying it at 100% and not 50% worked!

Comment: I actually saved over the version in the original post so just undone it and forked to an updated version. That link work now?

Comment: Yes it does. Looks great!