# z-index issue while transforming after pseudo-element with transition

Tags: html, css

I created a following button:

```css
button{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border:none;
  transition:.5s;
  position:relative;
  color:white;
}

button:hover{
background-color:blue;
  transform:translate(5px,5px);
}

button:hover:after{
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

button:after{
  content: '';
  transition:.5s;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```

When I hover over the button the top layer (red) appears to be going below the blue `after` pseudo-element. What should I change to keep the red layer on top at all times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having an issue because the transform is [creating a stacking context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903621/8620333) moving the pseudo element inside thus it can not more be behind the main element.

I would advise you to consider something else because relying on the pseudo element behind its parent element may create issue because the pseudo element can go behind other element.

Here is a basic example if I add a background to the body where you will partially see the pseudo element because it's behind the body.

```css
button{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border:none;
  transition: .5s;
  position:relative;
  color:white;
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
}

button:hover{
 bottom: -5px; 
 right: -5px;
}

button:hover:after{
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

button:after{
  content: '';
  transition:.5s;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

body,html {
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```

Here is another idea, where you don't need pseudo element and you can use a simple `box-shadow`:

```css
button{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border:none;
  transition: .5s;
  color:white;
  box-shadow:5px 5px 0 blue;
}

button:hover{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0 blue;
  transform:translate(5px,5px);
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```

---

Another idea with pseudo element where you have to use both of them:

```css
button{
  background-color:none;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border:none;
  transition: .5s;
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
button:before,
button:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:red;
  z-index:-1;
}
button:before {
  background:blue;
  transform:translate(5px,5px);
  transition: .5s;
}

button:hover{
  transform:translate(5px,5px);
}
button:hover:before{
  transform:translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can animate `bottom` and `right` properties to get the effect.

```css
button{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border:none;
  transition: .5s;
  position:relative;
  color:white;
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
}

button:hover{
 bottom: -5px; 
 right: -5px;
}

button:hover:after{
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

button:after{
  content: '';
  transition:.5s;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```