# Why does fixed overlay as child from sticky element not cover other sticky element

Tags: css, sticky

I'd like to have an overlay, that is "somewhere potentially deep" in the DOM.

There seems to be a problem or something I am doing wrong with `position: sticky` though.

If the overlay element is a child of a "position-sticky element", then other "position-sticky elements" are not covered correctly.

I created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lipp/pen/pXEQVM) demonstrating the problem.

Is there a reasonable explanation or solution/workaround for this?

Comment: here is the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56627794/8620333 (cannot close as duplicate) .. sticky create a stacking context making the fixed element trapped there and cannot cover external ones

Answer (score 0):

Update: As per the OP the yellow area needs to be on top always without the fade.

Add the `z-index: 0` to `input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after` class to fix the issue.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
section:last-of-type {
  background: purple;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
}
div {
  display: flex;
}
article {
  width: 50%;
}

article:first-child {
  height: 200vh;
  background: cyan;
}

article:last-child {
  background: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  top: 140px;
  height: calc(100vh - 140px);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section>Click me<input type="checkbox" /> I am NOT sticky</section>

<section>Click me<input type="checkbox" />I am sticky</section>
<div>
  <article>OK</article>
  <article>
    <h2>Not covered by overlay when clicking purple (which is sticky)</h2>
    <h2>Covered be overlay when clicking red
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that the sticky (yellow) becomes "inactive" with x-index -1. Inputs are not editable etc (I updated the codepen to show this).

Comment: you want the yellow area to be edited and at the same time the overlay should be on top ?

Comment: No. But the yellow are should be accessible without overlay

Comment: @lipp : did the CSS change help you to fix the issue ?