# Why does green div come on top of red div?

Tags: css, z-index

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBdaWE

In the codepen above I have 2 divs `red` and `blue`. Using `z-index` we make sure red is above blue even if it comes before `blue` in markup.

`green` is a child of `blue` with `z-index` of `9999`. Even though it's `z-index` is high it should be trapped inside `blue` which is clearly below `red`. As said in the CSS tricks article:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

> Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B.

How does `green` div, which is a child of `blue` is able to come on top of `red` div?

Comment: Because you have given z-index 999 to the green div, So it will be on the top of everything

Comment: @ThanveerShah `green` is child of `blue` that is under `red`. So how does it comes out of its parent over `red`?

Comment: two words: Stacking context & painting order. All explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!! note, all quotes here below with a * at the end are from [this source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

> > Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B.*
>
> How does `green` div, which is a child of `blue` is able to come on top of `red` div?

You have probably mis-interpret that sentence. It is meant for that situation where none of the elements have `z-index` set. If you style the elements without setting the `z-index`, it holds the truth. Look at the interactive example here below, which is without modifying the `z-index` of the elements.

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.red, .blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red  {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the following statement is true

> Without any `z-index` value, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top)*

However, it is not obvious first because blue's position is `static`, in contrary to the other two elements, whose `position` are `relative` (thus non-static). If you expect that blue is above red (and below green), then you have to change its `position` CSS attribute. It is also mentioned in the link, as quoted here below

> Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning.*

In the example here below, I have given the blue element (look for "ADDED") a non-static position value. This leads to a similar behavior as when all element's `position` are `static`: red comes first, then blue comes on top of it, followed by green on top of it because it is a child of blue (lower in hierarchy).

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.red, .blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red  {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative; /* !! ADDED !! */
}

.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, back at the first quote;

> Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B.*

This occurs when you are only giving the element B (in this situation, it is `.red`) a `z-index` value. In the example here below, I have added a `z-index` value to the red element.

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.red, .blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red  {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
  z-index:1; /* !! ADDED !! */
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See, the green element does not appear anymore. This is because red is above blue. And green is a part of the blue.

In yours question, you have given green another `z-index` value. This will overrule the current behavior so that it becomes above the red element as shown here below.

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.red, .blue {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.red  {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -50px;
  z-index:1;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2; /* !! ADDED !! */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the important part is to see if the blue element create or not a stacking context. If they do then the green will get trapped inside, if not the green is *free*. Without z-index on blue the green is *free*

Answer (score 1):

Look at your CSS file. The `z-index` of `.green` is `9999`.

EDIT: When `z-index` is `auto`, no stacking context is created. So red and blue have the same stacking context. This is why the children of blue doesn't work as expected of a nested element with a lower `z-index`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Yes. But it is a child of a div which is stacked below red.

Comment: @Abhimanyu z index still works it is no excuse for it to not work

Comment: @weegee I also linked the CSS tricks article and it says nesting plays role. Also adding `z-index: 0` on `blue` makes everything work as expected. Even though it does not change stacking order between `red` and `blue`.