# Why does the browser render the body behind elements with a negative z-index?

Tags: css, browser, rendering, z-index, web-standards

I discovered a strange problem, when I render a page with an element that has a negative z-index (`z-index: -1`) and call `document.elementsFromPoint`, the result is that visually the element with the negative `z-index` appears above the body but `elementsFromPoint` places the element between the `<html>` and `<body>` elements.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>A title</h1>
    </main>
    <img src="foo.bar" alt="foo bar">
  </body>
</html>
```

If I apply CSS to move the image on top of the heading like this:

```
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Then the stack that I will get under the `<h1>` from `elementsFromPoint` will be:

```
<img>
<h1>
<main>
<body>
<html>
```

Now if I modify that CSS to make the image fall under the heading:

```
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Then visually, the image appear below the heading but still appears above the `<body>`. However calling `elementsFromPoint` I now get:

```
<h1>
<main>
<body>
<img>
<html>
```

Notice that the `<img>` element is between the `<body>` and `<html>` elements. This makes sense because the `<body>` will have a default `z-index` of `0`, so the `<img>` element should be rendered beneath it.

But if that's the case, why is the browser rendering the image above the `<body>`? I have checked this in both Chrome and Firefox and the results are the same.

[Here is a working demo](https://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/NWKbPzm)

---

**Edit:** Here is a demonstration of this weird effect. The bread slices are both content from the `<body>` tag, the other two images are sandwiched in between.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/microsoft/209/bread_1f35e.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 110px;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

img + img {
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/microsoft/209/herb_1f33f.png" alt="greens in the sandwich">
<img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/microsoft/209/bacon_1f953.png" alt="meat between the bread">
```

Comment: default z-index is auto and not 0 ... and in your code you make it 0 and this will make the image above not behind. it get behind with auto

Comment: @TemaniAfif, fair point, that it's not actually set to `0` but either setting the `body` to have a `0` z-index` or `auto` results in the same visual order and order from `elementsFromPoint`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, default `z-index` is `auto` and not `0`. There is a difference because the last one will create a stacking context making the element inside it (even with negative `z-index`) to always be rendred above. More details here: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Then you are facing [background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds) which is a special behavior when setting background color to body element which will make you think that the element is not behind.

Then your image is set to `position:absolute` making it out of the flow thus it won't affect the height of the body so even if it's behind we can still see it.

Here is some examples to illustrate different cases:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>A polar bear</h1>
  <pre>
  </pre>
</main>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Polar_Bear_AdF.jpg" alt="A Polar Bear">
```

In the above the background is propagated from body to html, the image is rendred behind the body and the body height is equal to `h1`.

Let's disable the propagation by setting a background to `html`

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
}

html {
 background:red;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>A polar bear</h1>
  <pre>
  </pre>
</main>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Polar_Bear_AdF.jpg" alt="A Polar Bear">
```

Now it's more clear that we have the html (red) then the image then the body (black) and its content. You can also see that the height the body is restricted to its in-flow content.

Now let's add `z-index:0` to body:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index:0;
}

html {
 background:red;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>A polar bear</h1>
  <pre>
  </pre>
</main>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Polar_Bear_AdF.jpg" alt="A Polar Bear">
```

The body is now creating a stacking context forcing the image to be painted inside and the order is now html then body then its content (the image then the heading)

Comment: Fascinating, so browsers are handing the rendering of the backgrounds and the `elementsFromPoint` stack correctly, it's that there are special rules for ordering backgrounds. I tested putting text in the body and that did in fact appear above both the body background and the image. Strange but good to know. Thanks!