# When using transform:scale on parent, child element's dropdown goes under another row

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

So problem is that when I'm trying to scale my row on hover where I have my dropdown if my dropdownmenu is open it goes under next row.

How do I get it to stay in top?

I have tried z-index, but no help there. There maybe something I don't understand in using scale.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.myScale1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row myScale1">
    <div class="col ">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `transform` will create a stacking context making the dropdown inside it thus all the row (the stacking context) will be hidden by the next row following the painting order.

To avoid this, simply increase the `z-index` of the scaled row:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.myScale1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row myScale1">
    <div class="col ">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related question for more details about painting order and stacking context:

[Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)