# late rendered div is not respecting z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, svelte

I have a webpage made with svelte and I am trying to create a sort of tooltip for a div that should be displayed on hover.

So I wrote this:

```
<div
  class="test"
  style="background-color: {testcase.failure ? 'red' : 'green'}"
  on:mouseenter={() => (testcase.mouseover = true)}
  on:mouseleave={() => (testcase.mouseover = false)}>
  {#if (testcase.failure && testcase.mouseover)}
    <div class="failure">
      <div class="name">{testcase.class}:{testcase.name}</div>
      <div class="error">{testcase.failure}</div>
    </div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

and it works in the sense that the `failure` div is shown only on hover.
However it is of course shown underneath all elements that are "after" it in the DOM.

So I added a z-index to `failure`, but it does nothing. It is still displayed underneath everything despite having a much higher z-index.

After experimenting a bit I figured out that if I remove the if statement and simple always display the `failure` div, then it is "properly" displayed on top of everything else.

This seems really weird for me and I cannot figure out why it does this. Does anyone have any good explanation for it?
(I know that I can probably always display it and just change opacity or something to get the same effect, but I am curious about the root cause)

Comment: did you add `position:relative` to the div?

Comment: the "test" class is positioned relative and the "failure" is absolute. but since they have a position, z-index should work right?

Comment: test is also having a z-index?

Comment: huh... I moved that z-index to test and now it works. I thought it wouldn't matter, but I might have done something funky with the css somewhere

Comment: yes it matter because it may create a stacking context. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903621/8620333

Comment: More about stacking context and z-index explained by Kevil Powell here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uS8l4YRXbaw