# How to place a standalone fixed-Div layered between(z-index) a fixed Parent and Absolute-Child division?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have two fixed components:

1. *Parent* with its absolute positioned *Child*
2. *Between*

I have used z-index for all three elements but those aren't a must.
I cannot remove the `z-index:666` of the *parent* nor can I remove its `position:fixed` as it'll mess-up the site layout...

rest z-indices can be changed... the goal is to bring the *Between* element between *Parent* and *Child* elements...

Here's my Code:

```css
* {
  color: white;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 30vh;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1rem
}

#parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 666;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  background: orange;
  left: 30vw;
  z-index: 888;
}

#between {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40vh;
  background: green;
  left: 10vw;
  z-index: 777;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Parent
  <div id="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
<div id="between">
  Between
</div>
```

Comment: if you cannot remove fixed from the parent thne it's impossible

Comment: Can z-transform be used to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Temani Afif Maybe position: sticky can be used then? :(

Comment: sticky will not work the same as position:fixed

Comment: you can approximate with transform but you will mess the position:fixed

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/b7zd12nf/  but no more fixed position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea of solution that works but will break the `position:fixed`. It uses 3D transformation tricks

```css
body * {
  color: white;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 30vh;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1rem
}

#parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 666;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  background: orange;
  left: 30vw;
  z-index: 888;
  transform:translateZ(2px); /* here */
}

#between {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40vh;
  background: green;
  left: 10vw;
  z-index: 777;
}

html {
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* here */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Parent
  <div id="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
<div id="between">
  Between
</div>
```

Related: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)