# How does z-index work with its default values?

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

can anyone explain how z-index default value works in this snippet

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="">main element</a>
    <ul  class="first">
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I expected sub ul to be on the top

but I don't know how text from top level wrapped over text from lower level ?

I can notice sub ul [red one] on the top and it can hide the top level border

So I expected that ul here working like container so every child element will follow it

---

*I know If I give it z-index:1*

*will resolve it but I hope to understand the situation here if is possible*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about paiting order. First let's add a `top` value to better see what is happening:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 20%;
  top:-20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
  background: red;
}
a {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="">main element</a>
    <ul  class="first">
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note how the red element is above the first 3 elements and below the last 3 elements. If we check the specification related to [the painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) we can read the following:

> 8. All **positioned**, opacity or transform descendants, in **tree order** that fall into the following categories:
>
>    1. All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.
>         For those with **'z-index: auto'**, treat the element as if it created a new stacking context, **but any positioned descendants and descendants which actually create a new stacking context should be considered part of the parent stacking context**, not this new one.

The main trick is here. All your elements are positionned and no one has `z-index` specified so all will belong to the same stacking context and we will follow the tree order to paint them.

Following this logic we will have this order:

1. the `ul` with class `first` (the green box)
2. the first 3 `li` inside `ul.first`
3. the `ul` with class `foo` (the red box)
4. all the `li` inside `ul.foo`
5. the last 3 `li` inside `ul.first`

Adding a `z-index` will change the order and will also create some stacking context.

---

`z-index:0` on `ul.foo` will create a stacking context but will have no effect since we are already painting all the elements inside it right after it.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 20%;
  top:-20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
  background: red;
  z-index:0;
}
a {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="">main element</a>
    <ul  class="first">
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`z-index > 0` on `ul.foo` will move it to the top of everything since it will get painting at the step (9)

> 9. Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants with z-indices greater than or equal to 1 in z-index order (smallest first) then tree order.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 20%;
  top:-20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
  background: red;
  z-index:2;
}
a {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="">main element</a>
    <ul  class="first">
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`z-index < 0` on `ul.foo` will move it to the bottom of everything since it will get painting at the step (3)

> 3. Stacking contexts formed by positioned descendants with negative z-indices (excluding 0) in z-index order (most negative first) then tree order.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 20%;
  top:-20%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
  background: red;
  z-index:-2;
}
a {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="">main element</a>
    <ul  class="first">
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`z-index < 0` on `ul.foo` and `z-index` different from `auto` on `ul.first` will first paint the green box then `ul.foo` then all the `li` inside `ul.first`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 20%;
  top:-20%;
  border: 1px solid;
  z-index:0;
}

.foo {
  background: red;
  z-index:-2;
}
a {
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul >
  <li>
    <a href="">main element</a>
    <ul  class="first">
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
        <ul class="foo">
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
          <li class="secound"><a href="">Secound Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
      <li><a href="">First level</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Related question to get more details:

[Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)