# Is there a way to stack elements regardless of stacking order and context?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, z-index

I am working on a navigation bar for my react app and having problem displaying a drop-down menu under the navigation bar. I would like to have the drop-down menu to slide from the top but not covering the navigation bar in the progress.
I have my components structured as follow:

My NavBar component is specified with position fixed and a high enough z-index

```
<header>
   <nav className={classes.NavBar}>
      <NavItems />
   </nav>
</header>
```

NavItems contains a number of individual navigation items, the Dropdown component will show the drop-down menu when it is hovered

```
<NavItem link="/" exact="true">Home</NavItem>
<NavItem link="/destinations">Destinations</NavItem>
<NavItem link="/services">Services</NavItem>
<Dropdown label="My Trips">
   <DropdownItem link="/manage-booking">Manage Booking</DropdownItem>
   <DropdownItem link="/enquire">Enquire</DropdownItem>
</Dropdown>
<NavItem link="/about-us">About Us</NavItem>
```

My Dropdown component contains DropdownContent class which I want it to be under the NavBar

```
<ul className={classes.Dropdown}>
   {label}
   <div className={classes.DropdownContent}>
      {children}
   </div>
</ul>
```

I have known that setting low z-index for DropdownContent would not work since it has transform CSS property that set itself on a different stacking context. So, is there a way to place DropdownContent class under Navbar like in this case?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333 (you may find your answer at the very end of the accepted answer)

Comment: Great answer there! Thanks @TemaniAfif. Got my problem solve and I also got to understand z-index better. Very clear explanation!

Comment: good ;) I will then close the question as duplicate since you find what you needed there