# Display element over one with position: sticky

Tags: html, css, z-index, sticky

I need to display a dropdown content over an element that has `position: sticky` set.
Unfortunately manipulation with `z-index` didn't help much. The content shown on hover is still covered by next sticky element.

Full example presenting the problem with multiple applets: https://jsfiddle.net/tfkh2v0n/3/

Minimal example:

```css
.applet-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.applet {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sticky-header {
    top: 0px;
    position: sticky;
    background: #d1d1d1;
    z-index: 3;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 4;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gold;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="applet-container">
  <div class="applet">
      <div class="sticky-header">
        Sticky Header 
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">Content 1 that will be displayed over</div>
  </div>
    <div class="applet">
      <div class="sticky-header">Dropdown content should be displayed over this sticky header</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put your code in the question

Comment: even if it is as lengthy as in the jsfiddle example?

Comment: yes, and you are required to put the minimal code need to reproduce the issue and not your full project code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of all the `z-index` (you don't need any of them) and simply set `z-index` to the sticky element on hover.

```css
.applet-container {
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
}

.applet {
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.sticky-header {
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background: #d1d1d1;
  /*z-index: 3;*/
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*z-index: 4;*/
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gold;
  min-width: 160px;
  /*z-index: 5;*/
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  /*z-index: 5;*/
}

.sticky-header:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="applet-container">
  <div class="applet">
    <div class="sticky-header">
      Sticky Header
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content 1 that will be displayed over</div>
  </div>
  <div class="applet">
    <div class="sticky-header">Dropdown content should be displayed over this sticky header</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem in my application. So the way I understand it works is that the `sticky-header:hover` increases that particular header's `z-index` and the `dropdown` and `dropdown-content` inherirts the increased z-index.

Comment: @gregid it's not really inheritance but the drowpdown is place inside the stacking context created by the sticky element and I have increased the z-index of the stacking context making all the element inside on the top. related for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903621/8620333

Comment: thank you for the link to the stacking context - great explanation there!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the z-index to the `applet` divs. Give to the first `applet` a `z-index: 9999` and you will see that the dropdown will be over the others menu

Comment: if I understand you correctly you recommend applying individual `z-index` to each applet as in `<div class="applet" style="z-index: 9999;">` and then consecutively go down with index: 9998, 9997, etc. This could work but since my applets are added dynamically it is a bit problematic. Is there any other, generic way to achieve this?

Comment: i can't find a way, if there is. BTW, if you add them dynamically, then you probably can dynamically add the z-index (using the style attribute) @gregid

Comment: Yes, there just few problems with reordering, moving, etc. So not ideal but at least it works! If there will be no generic solution soon I will accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @gregid sure, i'll try to find other solution (possibly more generic )