# CSS Absolute / Relative Issue

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have a **parent element** that I have set `relative` on, and **child elements** that have `absolute`

However, those child elements when shown are still hidden for some reason (even after setting z-index), see the following code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="relative shadow-sm rounded-lg h-96">
    <ul class="mt-3 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/0e4bb7f1-352d-4cf9-b6bb-3c00c7a310a7'"
            wire:key="campaign--14" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">5 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(14)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(14)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(14)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/403f251d-fa34-426b-b623-76b6ba200f6d'"
            wire:key="campaign--13" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(13)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(13)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(13)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/fddbacf7-ed69-43cf-9355-0379237f9c53'"
            wire:key="campaign--12" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(12)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(12)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(12)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/37164604-0fa5-4d2d-a344-00ff7010c182'"
            wire:key="campaign--11" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(11)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(11)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(11)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/01c535bf-68bf-4bcd-b3a6-3239f5212650'"
            wire:key="campaign--10" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(10)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(10)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(10)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/de321988-5119-42ae-bd2d-a5984dae623d'"
            wire:key="campaign--9" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(9)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(9)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(9)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When you press the contextual menu, it should display above everything else, but it doesn't.

It should be so simple - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the `z-10` you are applying to the parent element. This one can be removed as it's useless. It's also due to the transformation you are applying to the element on hover.

Remove it and it will work fine.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="relative shadow-sm rounded-lg h-96">
    <ul class="mt-3 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/37164604-0fa5-4d2d-a344-00ff7010c182'"
            wire:key="campaign--11" >
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out relative col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(11)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(11)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(11)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/01c535bf-68bf-4bcd-b3a6-3239f5212650'"
            wire:key="campaign--10" >
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out relative col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(10)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(10)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(10)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/de321988-5119-42ae-bd2d-a5984dae623d'"
            wire:key="campaign--9" >
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out relative col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(9)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(9)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(9)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or keep the transformation and adjust the z-index of the parent on hover

```css
.z-10:hover {
  z-index:50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.8.0/alpine.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="relative shadow-sm rounded-lg h-96">
    <ul class="mt-3 grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/37164604-0fa5-4d2d-a344-00ff7010c182'"
            wire:key="campaign--11" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(11)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(11)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(11)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/01c535bf-68bf-4bcd-b3a6-3239f5212650'"
            wire:key="campaign--10" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(10)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(10)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(10)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
        <div onclick="location.href='campaign/de321988-5119-42ae-bd2d-a5984dae623d'"
            wire:key="campaign--9" class="z-10">
            <li
                class="cursor-pointer transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-0.5 hover:scale-100 col-span-1 flex items-center bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-sm">
                <div
                    class="rounded-md ml-2 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center w-16 h-16 text-white text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium bg-blue-500">
                    <svg class="text-white h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="M15 15l-2 5L9 9l11 4-5 2zm0 0l5 5M7.188 2.239l.777 2.897M5.136 7.965l-2.898-.777M13.95 4.05l-2.122 2.122m-5.657 5.656l-2.12 2.122">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 truncate">
                    <div
                        class="text-gray-900 text-sm leading-5 font-medium hover:text-gray-600 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Untitled Campaign</div>
                    <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">Leads: 3</p>
                    <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">14 hours ago</p>
                </div>

                <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false"
                    class="inline-block text-left">
                    <div>
                        <button @click.stop="" @click="open = !open"
                            class="flex items-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z">
                                </path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        class="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-50" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                            <div class="py-1">
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="exportCampaign(9)">Export</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showRenameModal(9)">Rename</a>
                                <a @click.stop=""
                                    class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900"
                                    wire:click="showDeleteModal(9)">Delete</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added a custom CSS but you can use `hover:z-50` if you adjust the configuration like explained here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

---

Related question to get more details about the issue: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)