# How can i make anchor tags clickable when using the function z index

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

the nav is set absolute to the headerContainer. And in motion it works fine.
It needs to drop from behind the headerContainer over the main content of the page. This way the content dissapears and the menu is on top.
I have done so by setting my main class to relative and a negative z-index: 2; because the nav is set to negativ -1;

Right now everything works and it looks good. The only problem is that the anchor tags inside my nav are not clickable anymore.

I have been searching for the answer but could not find anything related.
Is there anyone who can tell me why this occurs? I have yet to find a good solution for this.

What i want to happen seems so simple.. it needs to drop down from behind or at least create the idea its coming from behind the header..

I have tried setting the height of the nav to 0 and on click set it to 100%. That wil drop the menu as if it comes from behind. but gave me other problems like the anchors would come in later or sooner then the actual nav background.

Here is a snippet with the full example.

```js
let Btn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
let menu = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
Btn.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("show");
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
/* --- HEADER --- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.headerContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
/* --- Logo --- */
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand img {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
/* --- NAV --- */
header nav {
    z-index: -1;
    /* display: none; */
    padding: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: top 2s;
}
header nav.show {
    top: 100%;
}
header nav ul.mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.menuBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
/* --- MAIN --- */
main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- header-->
        <header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <!-- Logo or Brandname -->
                <div class="headerBrand">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://krijgeronline.nl/assets/img/logo.png" width="auto" height="80px"> Logo text</a>
                </div>
                <!-- END Logo -->
                <!-- Nav -->
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Thirth link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menuBtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <!-- END Nav -->
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header-->
        <!-- Main -->
        <main class="container">
            <section>
                <h1>This is a header</h1>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </section>
        </main>
        <!-- END Main-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add `position: relative;z-index: 0;` to the `body` element. Your negative z-index elements are going behind the body element which make them unclickable. By adding a z-index to the body you force the creation of a stacking context and you won't have this issue.

Full explanation here: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

```js
let Btn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
let menu = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
Btn.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("show");
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
/* --- HEADER --- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.headerContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
/* --- Logo --- */
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand img {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
/* --- NAV --- */
header nav {
    z-index: -1;
    /* display: none; */
    padding: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: top 2s;
}
header nav.show {
    top: 100%;
}
header nav ul.mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.menuBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
/* --- MAIN --- */
main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- header-->
        <header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <!-- Logo or Brandname -->
                <div class="headerBrand">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://krijgeronline.nl/assets/img/logo.png" width="auto" height="80px"> Logo text</a>
                </div>
                <!-- END Logo -->
                <!-- Nav -->
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Thirth link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menuBtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <!-- END Nav -->
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header-->
        <!-- Main -->
        <main class="container">
            <section>
                <h1>This is a header</h1>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </section>
        </main>
        <!-- END Main-->
```

You may argue that the elements aren't behind the body since we can clearly see them on the top of the background but this is due to [background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds) that move the background from the body to html element.

Add a background to html in your initial code to disable background propagation and you will notice how the elements are rendred behind the body:

```js
let Btn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
let menu = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
Btn.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("show");
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
html {
  background:red;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
/* --- HEADER --- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.headerContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
/* --- Logo --- */
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand img {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
/* --- NAV --- */
header nav {
    z-index: -1;
    /* display: none; */
    padding: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: top 2s;
}
header nav.show {
    top: 100%;
}
header nav ul.mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.menuBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
/* --- MAIN --- */
main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- header-->
        <header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <!-- Logo or Brandname -->
                <div class="headerBrand">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://krijgeronline.nl/assets/img/logo.png" width="auto" height="80px"> Logo text</a>
                </div>
                <!-- END Logo -->
                <!-- Nav -->
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Thirth link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menuBtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <!-- END Nav -->
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header-->
        <!-- Main -->
        <main class="container">
            <section>
                <h1>This is a header</h1>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </section>
        </main>
        <!-- END Main-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The z-index of any children are directly inherited from their parent - so if you have a child with a z-index of 100 inside of a parent with a z-index of -1, the child is 100 relative to the -1.

You should be able to build the header and menu without relying on z-index. For instance, I've taken the indexes out of your code and put this together (just add the animation): https://jsfiddle.net/efk6s1oj/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
/* --- HEADER --- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.headerContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
/* --- Logo --- */
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand img {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
/* --- NAV --- */
header nav {
    /* display: none; */
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: top 2s;
}

header nav ul.mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.menuBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* --- MAIN --- */

nav {
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
}

nav.show {
  top:100px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt answer my question.. why is it displayed properly but not functional?

I have tried display: none and display: block as well but this doesnt give the animation that i want.

So i came to this solution yet fell into another problem wich are the anchor tags not working..

Comment: It does answer your question - the links aren't functional because of your z-index - Your links display but are technically underneath another element - that's why they're not clickable. With my given solution you just need to animate the sliding.

Comment: Im sorry but it doesnt make sense to me. The element that is making it unclickable is the main section. If i remove that from the code i can click on the links.
So i set the main section to -2. Wich sets it behind the content that im showing.. 
Yet it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of effects and due to the problem you are pointing out, I use a different technique to simulate the drop effect.

Just position the `<nav>` where you want and work with the max-height from 0 to a large enough value, and remove all negative z-index.

Find the solution in the snippet bellow

```js
let Btn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
let menu = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
Btn.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("show");
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
/* --- HEADER --- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.headerContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
/* --- Logo --- */
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand img {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
/* --- NAV --- */
header nav {
    z-index: 9;
    /* display: none; */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: absolute;
    /*top: -100px;
    left: -1px;*/
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    /*transition: top 2s;*/
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
}
header nav.show {
    /*top: 100%;*/
    max-height: 500px;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease, padding 0.5s ease;
}
header nav ul.mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
.menuBtn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
/* --- MAIN --- */
main {
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: -2;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- header-->
        <header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <!-- Logo or Brandname -->
                <div class="headerBrand">
                    <a href=""><img src="https://krijgeronline.nl/assets/img/logo.png" width="auto" height="80px"> Logo text</a>
                </div>
                <!-- END Logo -->
                <!-- Nav -->
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Thirth link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="menuBtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
                <!-- END Nav -->
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header-->
        <!-- Main -->
        <main class="container">
            <section>
                <h1>This is a header</h1>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </section>
        </main>
        <!-- END Main-->
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have allready tried working with the height and there are several new problems i run unto using this method.
In your snippet you can also see that there is a small padding or margin on the right wich pushes the website. 
Also when i use this method of a fixed height so to say i lose the ability to add new content in the nav. without having to turn to code again to set a new fixed height.
Is there a way to make this more "maintenance free" so to say..
Also it does not explain why my z-index is not working. If im correct im not using the z-index wrong.

Comment: The method in the snippet is not using a fixed height. it uses a max-height which allows you to add as many menu items as you want. I used 500px, but if you think you are going to use more than 10 items, which is not a good idea for usability reasons, then you can set a larger max-height.
I'm not sure what you mean about the margins, but I think margins were not your issue, were they? However, I positioned the nav to the left for you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing this with `z-index` especially negatives. Your links don't work because they are behind transparent content by `z-index`.

Instead change the order the elements are in the page, which keeps it much simpler.

I've stripped out your fonts/styles just to keep this simple, and switched from animating `top` to animating `transform`:

```js
let Btn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
let menu = document.querySelector("nav");
let icon = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
Btn.onclick = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle("show");
  icon.classList.toggle("fa-times");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #1F1F1F;
  font-size: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1F1F1F;
}


/* --- HEADER --- */

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.headerContainer,
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.headerContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}


/* --- Logo --- */

.headerBrand {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.headerBrand img {
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}


/* --- NAV --- */

nav {
  padding: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

nav.show {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

nav ul.mainMenu {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.menuBtn {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
}


/* --- MAIN --- */

main {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a9b20b17fc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- First content, everything else appears on top -->
<main class="container">
  <section>
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
    <p>This is some text</p>
  </section>
</main>

<!-- Then nav, on top of content, under header -->
<nav>
  <ul class="mainMenu">
    <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thirth link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Finally header, on top of everything -->
<header>
  <div class="headerContainer">
    <div class="headerBrand">Whatever</div>
    <div class="menuBtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However i do not understand how my nav would be behind a transparant main content ( in my code ). In my understanding the z-index is a layering option. So if the layers are set correctly there should be no interference. I do like the way you solved this problem. I do think its quite weird to set up my code like that only because of my nav.

Comment: @RaRaRitalin `z-index` is a layering _override_, but a) it only applies within it's own stacking context and b) negative values don't really work. You're far better off layering by the document order rather than by `z-index`, and only set it in very corner cases. When you're using grid or absolute layouts (as here) it's best to order your HTML elements by bottom-first, topmost-last because that is so much easier to maintain than trawling through CSS files and cascades looking for `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Main changes include changing the nav element to a div element with class as headerNav & making corresponding changes.

also z-index works just dont go in negative push header up to +ve numbers not pushing nav behind in -ve number.

This is the closest best solution for your problem.

```js
let Btn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
    let menu = document.querySelector(".headerNav");
    let icon = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
    Btn.onclick = () => {
        menu.classList.toggle("show");
        icon.classList.toggle("fa-times");
    }
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    align-content: center;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    color: #1F1F1F;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
}

.headerContainer, .headerNav, .container{
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:1rem;
}
.headerContainer{
    height: 7rem;
    z-index: 3;
}
.container{
    padding:2rem;
}
.headerBrand a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.headerBrand img {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}
.menuBtn {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFF;
}
.headerNav{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10rem;
    transition: top .5s;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 1rem;
    
}
.headerNav.show{
    top: 7rem;
}

.mainMenu{
    list-style: none;
}
.mainMenu li a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- header-->
<header>
    <div class="headerContainer">
        <!-- Logo or Brandname -->
        <div class="headerBrand">
            <a href=""><img src="https://krijgeronline.nl/assets/img/logo.png" width="auto" height="80px"> Logo text</a>
        </div>
        <!-- END Logo -->
        <div class="menuBtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
        <!-- END Nav -->
    </div>
    <!-- Nav -->
    <div class="headerNav">
        <ul class="mainMenu">
            <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Thirth link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- END header-->
<!-- Main -->
<main class="container">
    <section>
        <h1>This is a header</h1>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <p>This is some text</p>
        <p>This is some text</p>
    </section>
</main>
<!-- END Main-->
</body>
```