# z-index issue for css and html

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, z-index

**Here is a simple code **

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
}


.two {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  
  z-index: 10;
}

.twenty {
  
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 500;
}


.three {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}


.four {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 120px;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">

  <div class="two">

    <div class="twenty">
        Can pink be above green?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="three">
  <div class="four">

  </div>
</div>
```

How to make the pink square to be above the green square?  Is it possible with CSS changes only without HTML changes? Why z-index applied to the .twenty class doesn't work in this case?
Thank you.

**This question is NOT a duplicate of** [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child) :

**In this question we'd like the child to cover, not the parent!**

Comment: simply remove z-index from two

Answer (score 2):

All layers, except the twentieth, should not have Z order. We specify absolute an order and an order of a layer on Z.

```
.twenty{
position: absolute;
...
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `.four` with a lower `z-index` than `.two` which is the element that contains `.twenty` but this may not be the expected result (green also becomes under the orange).

It's not possible without changing the `HTML` structure, like putting `.twenty` inside `.four`, or redefining all the indexes. This is how the stacking context works.

Given this code:

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="One"></div>
  <div class="Two"></div>
</div>
<div class="B">
  <div class="Three"></div>
</div>
```

### From the top view

[image]

### From the side view

[image]

Lear more about the stacking context:

- [CSS stacking contexts and z-index made easy](https://equinusocio.dev/blog/css-stacking-context-made-easy/)
- [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can ;)... if orange gets a higher z-index than green...

```
.two {
   ...  
   z-index: 12;
}
```

It's because pink is a child of orange...

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. With your solution the green also becomes under the orange, not just under the pink.

Comment: @Artemiy Dyakov did it - it works...