# what does transform : none computes the browser?

Tags: html, css, transform

is transform : none computes to `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)` or something else

i want to reset transform , which approach is good for reset transform.

```
<style>
.box{
   height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: red;
transition: 0.5s;
transform: translate(100px) rotate(45deg);
}
  / * approach one  */
.box:hover{
transform: none; /* dont know what does browser computes to transform: none*/
}
  / * approach two  */
.box:hover{
transform: translate(0) rotate(0); /* browser computes matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) */
}
  / * approach three  */
.box:hover{
transform: translate(0); /* browser compute matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) */
}
<style>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: it computes to *none*

Comment: did u check ie 11 it computes  transform: none to matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) but other browser dont show matrix

Answer (score 2):

> which approach is good for reset transform.

That's not the right question to be asked because they are not the same to start with and this is very important.

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-property):

> Any computed value **other than none** for the transform affects **containing block and stacking context**, as described in § 2 The Transform Rendering Model.

Also

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value **other than none** for the transform property results in the creation of a stacking context.

The creation of stacking context is something you should be aware of because it can impact your layout.

Related: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: transform: none; /*  what does browser computes to transform: none ?*/

Comment: @codenewbie I already replied to this by saying it computes to *none*. Not sure what is not clear

Comment: what does none means ? what matrix does it computes ?

Comment: @codenewbie none means none, there is no matrix ...

Comment: if transform none does not create matrix then how does it animate ? @keyframes animate{ 0%{transform: rotate(180deg;} 100%{transform:none}}

Comment: @codenewbie maybe **you** need to learn more ;) read the Spec before giving me lessons. When dealing with animation we have a complete different story and in this case we use the "interpolation" to identify each transform: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#interpolation-of-transforms

Comment: thanks , If both Va and Vb are none:
Vresult is none. what is va and vb  here ?  i did understand meaning of these