# Two borders, second only right and bottom with a break

Tags: css, border, z-index, pseudo-element

I can't figure out, how I can achieve borders like this:

[image]

I was trying with after pseudoelement, like below but I learned from this topic: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child) that it's impossible.

I was thinking also about box shadow and outline but nothing seems to be a good solution. Any idea, please?

```css
.wp-block-group.is-style-black-blue-border {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wp-block-group.is-style-black-blue-border::after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-group is-style-black-blue-border">
  <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you didn't read the duplicate correctly. It's possible if you remove the z-index:1 from your code

Comment: I tried before I posted this question and it didn't help. You just can cover child with a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use box-shadow to create a similar effect. See below.

Edited to add: The effect can be done, see below

```css
.wp-block-group.is-style-black-blue-border {
  position: relative;
  background-color:white;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  
}

.wp-block-group.is-style-black-blue-border::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-group is-style-black-blue-border">
  <div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wp-block-group__inner-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 2px #ffffff, 8px 8px 0px 4px #0000ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp-block-group__inner-container">
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted and thank you for your answer, but it isn't exactly what I need. Note corners. They don't look same as on project when using box-shadow.

Comment: How about this? https://codepen.io/adamuk73/pen/zYjZrvK

Comment: @maja *but it isn't exactly what I need* --> don't accept answers if they don't solve your issue. You are sending a wrong signal to futures user and creating confusion.

Comment: It was probably for the codepen. I've edited the main post so the given answer matches maja's requirements so it makes sense to other readers.