# z-index not working with pseudo element, it is above the parent no matter what

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack two circles. One is the green circle (Parent), the white circle with the purple outline is the pseudo element. The white circle should be **UNDER** the green circle.

After applying `z-index:-1` to the pseudo element, no changes are seen. Likewise if I apply `z-index: 999` to the parent and `z-index: -1` to the pseudo element.

Where am I going wrong here?

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="settings">
                    <div class="block__circle"></div>
                    <div class="settings__inner">
                      <div class="block"></div>
                      <div class="block"></div>
                      <div class="block"></div>
                      <div class="block"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.settings {
          position: relative;
          .block {
            &__circle {
              display: block;
              width: rem(70);
              height: rem(70);
              border-radius: 50%;
              background: $green;
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              &::after {
                z-index: -1;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                width: rem(80);
                height: rem(80);
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: #fff;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                border: 1px solid $primary;
              }
            }
          }
          &__inner {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            gap: rem(5);
            justify-content: space-between;
            // each child, width 50%;
            > * {
              display: block;
              width: calc(50% - rem(5));
              height: rem(175);
              border: 1px solid $primary;
            }
            .block {
              &:nth-child(1) {
                border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
              }
              &:nth-child(2) {
                border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
              }
              &:nth-child(3) {
                border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
              }
              &:nth-child(4) {
                border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

CSS (For codepens)

```
.settings {
          position: relative;
          .block {
            &__circle {
              display: block;
              width: 70px;
              height: 70px;
              border-radius: 50%;
              background: #00a99d;
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              &::after {
                z-index: -1;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                width: 80px;
                height:80px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: #fff;
                z-index: -1;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                border: 1px solid red;
              }
            }
          }
          &__inner {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            gap: 5px;
            justify-content: space-between;
            // each child, width 50%;
            > * {
              display: block;
              width: calc(50% - 5px);
              height: 175px;
              border: 1px solid red;
            }
            .block {
              &:nth-child(1) {
                border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
              }
              &:nth-child(2) {
                border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
              }
              &:nth-child(3) {
                border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
              }
              &:nth-child(4) {
                border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using transform will [create a stacking context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child/54903621#54903621) causing issues with the `position` and `z-index` of pseudo and parent element.

Alternate approach to get the desired effect would be to create the pseudo element in the main `.settings` div.

I'm not sure if it helps your purpose but you can try.

```css
.settings {
  position: relative;
}

.settings .block__circle {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #00a99d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.settings::after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.settings__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.settings__inner>* {
  display: block;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 175px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.settings__inner .block:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
}

.settings__inner .block:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.settings__inner .block:nth-child(3) {
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
}

.settings__inner .block:nth-child(4) {
  border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <div class="block__circle"></div>
  <div class="settings__inner">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```