# How to beat a sibling stacking context with the highest z-index value

Tags: html, css, z-index

Given the following situation, how could you ensure that `.green` would appear above `.blue` by only modifying the CSS of `.green`? `.blue` has the highest z-index value possible of `2147483647` and cannot be changed.

My understanding is that these two elements already have their own stacking contexts, so no trickery like `transform: scale(1)` would work here.

Is there a way to do it?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 2147483647; // maximum value
}
```

```html
<div class="green">Must appear above</div>
<div class="blue">Cannot modify</div>
```

Comment: The real question should be why does blue have the max z-index and cannot be changed?

Comment: It is part of another system that cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure a solution exists given your requirements, but can you not override the z-index property with higher specificity either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3D transform can do it but pay attention to the potential side effects of transform:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translateZ(1px); /* 1px is enough */
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 2147483647; /* maximum value */
}

body {
  transform-style:preserve-3d; /* this is mandatory*/
}
```

```html
<div class="green">Must appear above</div>
<div class="blue">Cannot modify</div>
```

Related: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: Technically it's solved the question, but unfortunately it doesn't work where I'm having the issue.