# Setting a blending mode for a pseudo-element

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to recreate a Photoshop effect in CSS. I have a large sized text on an image background, and I would like the text to have a light colored shadow. This effect is produced in Photoshop using the Outer Glow effect, with the glow having "screen" blending mode.

[image: The effect I am trying to recreate]

Since the shadow has large spread (large dilation of the shadow), using the `text-shadow` property is impractical since it creates blobs on large sizes and the effect simply looks different from the preview above. Because of that, I am creating a shadow-like blurred background below the text in `::after`. This allows me to make it smoothly blurred (no blobs).

[image: Result of HTML & CSS below]

I would like the shadow-like background in the `::after` presudo-element to have a special blending mode, specifically `screen`. I know I can use `mix-blend-mode` in general, but it does not seem to work in this scenario. Is there any way to set blending mode for the `::after` pseudo-element?

This is what I have:
CSS:

```
.container {
  padding: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("../images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: -2pt;
  position: relative;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0pt auto -10pt auto;
  padding: 10pt 30pt;
  z-index: 100;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container h1::after {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(
      circle at center,
      rgba(224,235,245,0.9) 20%,
      rgba(224,235,245,0.8) 90%
  );
  border-radius: 50px;
  filter: blur(15px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
  <h1>Hello World! This is a long text.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to add `position: relative` to the h1 so the pseudo element use it as reference then add `z-index` to the container to create a stacking context but don't set any `z-index` on the h1.

Related question for more detail: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

```css
.container {
  padding: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1018/800/300") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: -2pt;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0pt auto -10pt auto;
  padding: 10pt 30pt;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.container h1::after {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(
      circle at center,
      rgba(224,235,245,0.9) 20%,
      rgba(224,235,245,0.8) 90%
  );
  border-radius: 50px;
  filter: blur(15px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World! This is a long text.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Many, many thanks for that. Although the edits you made absolutely make sense, I think I would give up before I would realize this. You just made my day :)