# ::after element doesn't works properly in hover status

Tags: html, css

when the element are leaving the status of hovering, it displays on top of the parent element. Below the code.

```css
.btn-sound {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: #FF3F76;
  transition: all 0.275s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.btn-sound::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #009792;
}

.btn-sound:hover {
  webkit-transform: translateX(-5px) translateY(6px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-5px) translateY(6px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-5px) translateY(6px);
  transform: translateX(-5px) translateY(6px);
  background: #009792;
}

.btn-sound:hover::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="btn-sound">
  <a href="index.html">
    <p class="text-button">Home</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

the :after item should stay behind the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update the hover effect like below. Related question to understand the use of the 3D transform: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

```css
.btn-sound {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: #FF3F76;
  transition: all 0.275s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.btn-sound::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset:0;
  transform: translate3d(-6px,6px,-1px);
  border: 2px solid #009792;
  transition: inherit;
}

.btn-sound:hover {
  transform: translate(-6px,6px);
  background: #009792;
}

.btn-sound:hover::after {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,-1px);
}
```

```html
<li class="btn-sound">
  <a href="index.html">
    <p class="text-button">Home</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: in, run code snippet, the normal state it's wrong, because the ::after element is on top of his parent.

Comment: @AleSparano it's below (tested on Firefox, Chrome and Edge)

Comment: thank you very much i’ll try it and works great. But why on iOS and iPadOS devices, the 3D transform doesn’t take effect, even if it said it’s completely supported??