# Video Overlay not working with reactjs styled components

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add an overlay to a vdieo that's playing in the background. However, the overlay seems to not show for some reason. What am i doing wrong? Below is the following code: And yes i do understand that I have the background color element in every component, that was me trying to get the overlay to show.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import styled from 'styled-components'; 
import VideoBg from '../assets/landing-page-video-1.webm';

const Home = () => {
  return ( 
    <VideoContainer> 
        < Overlay className="overlay">  
         <video className="BgVideo"src={VideoBg} autoPlay loop muted />  
         </Overlay> 
     
    </VideoContainer> 
    
  )
}

const Overlay = styled.div `
 & .overlay{
    z-index: 1; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) !important;

    
 }
`

const VideoContainer = styled.div ` 
& .BgVideo{  
    z-index: 1;
    bottom:0; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    left:0; 
    width: 100Vw; 
    height: 100vh; 
    object-fit: cover; 
    object-position: center; 
    margin-top: 0;  
    position:fixed;     
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) !important;

};  
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-family: Impact; 
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100vh; 
right:0; 
top:0; 
z-index: -1; 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) !important;`
`
```

I'm just trying to put a dark overlay over the video because i plan on putting text over the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `& .overlay` is not selecting anything. It should be changed to `&.overlay` removing the space between.

Next, with the current `<Overlay> <video> </Overlay>` structure, there is no way to make video appear below the **semi transparent** parent div (`overlay`) even if you set `z-index:100` on overlay or `z-index:-100` on the video. There are [SO Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child) and [articles](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) related to [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) you can find.

Without changing your JSX structure, You could instead add a pseudo element like such: (I've set opacity to `.5` instead of `.1` to make the example clearer.)

```js
const Home = () => {
  return ( 
    <VideoContainer> 
        <Overlay className="overlay">  
            <video className="BgVideo"src={VideoBg} autoPlay loop muted />  
         </Overlay> 
    </VideoContainer> 
  )
}

const Overlay = styled.div`
 &::after{
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important;
 }
`

const VideoContainer = styled.div` 
& .BgVideo{  
    bottom:0; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    left:0; 
    width: 100Vw; 
    height: 100vh; 
    object-fit: cover; 
    object-position: center; 
    margin-top: 0;  
    position:fixed;     
};  

bottom:0; 
left:0; 
right:0; 
top:0; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-family: Impact; 
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100vh; 
`
```

Comment: ooooooooh I see I learned something today. Thank you so much!