The z-index is not working when the div is animated
Even after applying z-index -1 on the ::after the stacking context of the ::after is not the way I want it to be and I have watched and researched a lot and still am unable to solve this issue I have read a lot of answers here but still no help


body {
  height: 97vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 200px 0 0 0;
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<div class="container">
</div>




In the posted demo, what exactly is going wrong?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child

To get the blue shape spinning behind the red container, you could add a wrapper around your container, use the ::after on the wrapper and set it to be behind the container with z-index.


body {
  height: 97vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: blue;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 200px 0 0 0;
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>




You might achieve the same easier just using border :


body {
  height: 97vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background: red padding-box;
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 4vmin;
  border-color:#00f #0000 #0000;
  animation: spinner 2s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes spinner {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
<div class="container">
</div>




wow I learnt a new thing thanks

@ritiksharma, happy to help! You'd probably find useful CSS-Loaders by great Temani Afif
