CSS setting child position on top of their parent
I would like to design the image below using HTML and CSS.

And the image below is the output of the code I have implemented.

As you may have noticed, I couldn't place the blue card on top of the parent card and move it to the right.
Even though I set the parent to relative and the child to absolute, when I move it, it shifts within the parent.


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card-top {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.card-center {
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FF9696;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card-center::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
  /*opacity: 0.2;*/
}

.card-center-left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.card-center-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
}

.card-bottom {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
<div class="card-top"></div>

<div class="card-center">
  <div class="card-center-left"></div>
  <div class="card-center-right"></div>
  <p>SAMPLE TEXT</p>
</div>

<div class="card-bottom"></div>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897916/why-cant-an-element-with-a-z-index-value-cover-its-child

Firstly you have to allow overflow on the card so the blue element isn't truncated. Then you can use the combination translation syntax to shift horizontally as well. Note that I modified the card's width to consider this overflow.


:root {
  --primaryColor: #E91515;
  --secondaryColor: #FF9696;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card-top {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: var(--primaryColor);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.card-center {
  width: calc(100% - 100px); /* <------------------------- HERE */
  height: 300px;
  /* overflow: hidden; <---------------------------------- HERE */
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--secondaryColor);
  padding: 20px;
}

.card-center::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: var(--primaryColor);
  z-index: -1;
}

.card-center-left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.card-center-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #235396;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%); /* <------------------------- HERE */
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.card-bottom {
  width: 70%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
<div class="card-top"></div>

<div class="card-center">
  <div class="card-center-left"></div>
  <div class="card-center-right"></div>
  <p>SAMPLE TEXT</p>
</div>

<div class="card-bottom"></div>



